# How to expand converts a CSV file to a space-delimited file? Scalar spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I has a `CSV` file. 
This is my Input:

```
,"",3,"a_b","cde 
f\gh","i j","k,""l"
```

Now, I want to convert `CSV` file to a space-delimited file. What should I do?

This is Specifications:

1. Data that is recognized as comma-delimited includes 
   string 0 (not enclosed in double-quotes) and "string 1" (enclosed in double quotes).
2. Empty string 0 is converted to 0, empty-string 1 is 
   converted to `"_"`. 
   (`-z` option changes `0` in string0, 
   `-n` option changes `_` in string 1)
3. Escaped double quotes inside string 1 are converted to single `"`. 
   You cannot use double quotes in string 0.
4. Half-width spaces inside any string are converted to `"_"` 
   (`-s` option changes `_`)
5. `-e` option precedes `"_"` (or the character specified by `-s` option) and 
   `"\"` by `"\"`.
6. `-q` option eliminate preceding `"\"` form `"\""` and `"\\"`.
7. `\r\n` at the end of a line is automatically converted to `\n`.
8. Any `\n` inside string 1 is converted to `"\n"`.
9. The final line does not require a linefeed (`\n`).

I want to have the desired output result as below. Please help me.

```
0 _ 3 a\_b cde\nf\\gh i_j k,"l
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use itto-csv https://github.com/gekomad/itto-csv to tokenize the csv

```
implicit val csvFormat: com.github.gekomad.ittocsv.parser.IttoCSVFormat = com.github.gekomad.ittocsv.parser.IttoCSVFormat.default
import com.github.gekomad.ittocsv.util.StringUtils._

val csvString = "1,foo"
val stringList = tokenizeCsvLine(csvString) //  Some(List("1", "foo")))
```

and apply your specifications to stringList

```
stringList.getOrElse(???).map(field => yourSpec(field))
```