# How to convert a space delimited file to a CSV file in Scalar spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I has a `CSV` file. 
This is my Input:

```
a _ \_ \ b_c b\_c "
```

Now, I want to convert a space delimited file to a CSV file. What should I do?

Fields not specified are considered "String 0" and are not enclosed
in quotes.

This is Specifications:

```
1.The string "_" by itself is converted to a null string.
( -n option changes "_" )

2.The string \c is converted to c.

3.The backslash character \ by itself is converted to a space

4.The underscore is converted to a space if it occurs in a string.
( -s option changes "_" )

5.\n at the end of a line is converted automatically to \r\n.

6.Within String 1, " is converted to "".
```

I want to have the desired output result as below. Please help me.

```
"a","","_"," ","b c","b_c",""""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements are a little bit confusing to me, but you can try with this (which produces the expected output):

```scala
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val input = "a _ \\_ \\ b_c b\\_c \""

// List of replacements required (first replacement will be apply first)
val replacements: List[(Regex, String)] = List(
  ("""^_$""".r,         ""),
  ("""(?<!\\)_""".r,    " "),
  ("""\\(.)""".r,       "$1"),
  ("""\\""".r,          " "),
  (""""""".r,           "\"\""))

def applyReplacements(inputString: String, replacements: List[(Regex, String)]): String =
  replacements match {
    case Nil =>
      inputString
    case replacement :: tail => 
      applyReplacements(
        replacement._1.replaceAllIn(inputString, replacement._2),
        tail)
  }

def processLine(input: String): String = {
  val inputArray = input.split(" ")
  val outputArray = inputArray.map(x => applyReplacements(x, replacements))
  val finalLine = outputArray.map(x => s"""\"${x}\"""").mkString(",")

  // Use s"${finalLine}\r\n" instead if you need the '\r\n' ending
  finalLine
}

processLine(input)
// output:
// String = "a","","_"," ","b c","b_c",""""
```

Probably you will have to apply some modifications to fully adapt it to your requirements (which are not fully clear to me).

If you need to apply this over a Spark RDD, you will have to put `processLine` in a `map` so that it processes every line in the RDD.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you expert. Based on your solution, I have solved the problem. Also, can you help me solve this similar problem? Please refer to the link below. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524296/how-to-expand-converts-a-csv-file-to-a-space-delimited-file-scalar-spark"